# Cell color based on its number value javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I have a table in a DJango template and i would like to dynamiclly assign a color of the number of the cell based on the number itself

if the number of the cell is higher than 95.00% green
btw 91.00% and 95.00% yellow
and lower than 91.00% red

I write a for cycle in javascript but seems that it takes to long to go from 00.01% to 100.00%
and the page never ends loading

This is the simple table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>AR</th>
        <th>CL</th>
        <th>UY</th>
    </tr>
        <td>VENTAS</td>
        <td id="100.00">100.00%</td>
        <td id="88.00">88.00%</td>
    <tr>
        <td>ADMIN</td>
        <td id="95">95.00%</td>
        <td id="97">97.00%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CALL</td>
        <td id="90">90.00%</td>
        <td id="65">65.00%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried adding an ID HTML TAG to every cell with the number of the value of the cell and writhing the following js code:

```
  function semaforo() {
    var value = 0.01
    while ( value < 99.95)
    var x = document.getElementById(value);
    x.style.color = "red";
    value = value + 0.01
  }
semaforo()
```

Comment: Please share the code you have tried

Comment: I have just editing my post with my attemp. Thanks you very much!

Comment: I made [this](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/LYPKZWQ) awhile back, probably find it helpful for your scenario.

Comment: IDs should not start with a number if you want any backwards compatibility. Also, note that only the `var x = document.getElementById(value);` line is repeated in your `while` since you're not using brackets. Thus, `value` is always 0.01 and you have an infinite loop.